# mootools changing an elements inline css

Tags: javascript, css, dom, mootools

I have some HTML that looks like this,

```
<div id="mb_contents" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; width: 600px; height: 450px;">
```

I am trying to turn the visibilty to hidden using this js/mootools,

```
$('mb_overlay').set('styles', {
            'visibilty': 'hidden',
        });
```

However nothing seems to be working, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method called [`setStyle`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style). In your case you'd use it like this:

```
$('mb_overlay').setStyle('visibility', 'hidden');
```

I think what you are actually doing with your code is setting an attribute called `styles`, which doesn't really exist.

Comment: many thanks is there a way to add a 2 second delay before this method gets fired?

Comment: Yes, I think `$('mb_overlay').setStyle('visibilty', 'hidden').delay(2000);` would do it.

Comment: mq.chen, you're wrong. `el.set('styles', {});` is the correct way of adding styles.

Answer (score 3):

You've misspelled "visibility"

This works just fine:

```
$('mb_contents').set('styles', {
    'visibility': 'hidden'
});
```